# How to create a simple numpy array using the C API, with proper memory management?

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, memory-management

I have two related questions regarding creating a numpy array using the C API. Given a newly created numpy array:

```
    std::vector<double> vec({0.1, 0.2});
    int length = vec.size();
    double* data = new double[length];
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), data); 
    PyObject* obj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &length, NPY_DOUBLE, (void*)data);
```

1. How do I ensure proper memory management?

   I didn't want to give `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` a pointer to `vec.size()` since that's owned by `vec` so I copied the data into newly allocated memory. However, will numpy/python "just know" it needs deleting at end of scope? The docs mention about setting the `OWNDATA` flag, is this appropriate for heap-allocated memory?
2. How do I get a `PyArrayObject*` from a `PyObject*` returned from `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`?

   All the [new array creation mechanisms](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html?highlight=array%20api#creating-arrays) such as `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` return a `PyObject*`, but if you want to do anything using the numpy c api, you need a `PyArrayObject*`.

## Edit

I was able to do an `reinterpret_cast` for 2, for instance:

```
    int owned = PyArray_CHKFLAGS(reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject *>($result), NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(reinterpret_cast< PyArrayObject*>($result), NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
    owned = PyArray_CHKFLAGS(reinterpret_cast< PyArrayObject *>($result), NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
    if (!owned){
        throw std::logic_error("PyArrayObject does not own its memory");
    }
```

Still not sure if this is the "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1:

If the data ownership should be passed to the PyObject returned by PyArray_SimpleNewFromData then OWNDATA must be set. In this case the memory must be heap allocated, because stack allocated variables are released as soon as the scope of the variable is left.
PyObject contains a reference count to manage the underlying memory. When the reference count is decremented to 0 then the object is deleted [(Py_INCREF,Py_DECREF)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html).

Regarding 2:

[PyArrayObject](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/types-and-structures.html?highlight=pyarrayobject#c.PyArrayObject) is a struct which contains the variable ob_base of type PyObject.
This PyObject is returned from PyArray_SimpleNewFromData.
Since ob_base is the first variable of PyArrayObject, reinterpret_cast can be used to obtain PyArrayObject from PyObject.
[Py_TYPE](https://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject) can be used to check the type of a PyObject.

Comment: I tried `PyArrayObject * arr = Py_TYPE(obj);` which errors with `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'PyTypeObject *' to 'PyArrayObject *'`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I wasn't able to obtain a pointer to `PyArrayObject` using `Py_TYPE`, I was however able to do `PyArrayObject* arr = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(obj);`